# Execution sequence in loop with if condition

Tags: loops, if-statement, sequence, wait

In my loop below the instructions are not executed one after the other, but out of order.
Some do not wait until the previous ones are finished to execute.
For example all displays with echo are done in advance when it loops.
I tried to put & at the end of each  instruction it didn't work

My loop contains if condition

Thanks for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=Mnt.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read dom alias port ver
do
ssh -n $alias "
 echo =======================================================
               echo $alias
 echo =======================================================

                        if [ ${ver} = "v3" ]
                        then
               

                       instruction 1
                        ........
                        ........
                        ........
                       instruction n

                       else
instruction A
........
........
........
instruction X

                        
                        fi
               exit" & >> $(date +%Y%m%d).log &
```

Answer (score 0):

It workes by adding wait  like this

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=Mnt.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read dom alias port ver
do
ssh -n $alias "
 echo =======================================================
               echo $alias
 echo =======================================================

                        if [ ${ver} = "v3" ]
                        then
               

                       instruction 1
                        ........
                        ........
                        ........
                       instruction n

                       else
instruction A
........
........
........
instruction X

                        
                        fi
                        wait
               exit"  >> $(date +%Y%m%d).log
```

wait